How to add a custom Font to Itext7 library in jetpack Compose
I want to build android app that generates pdf file, but I want to add custom font that's suitable with app purpose.
I tried to use string path "src/main/...etc" but it didn't work
Reading IText7 documentation was really painful, any solution?

You need to put down Font in /res/fonts/ and use them in code

I want to add the font to pdf not app,
I tried similar solution like that but it didn't work

I'm already using custom font for my PDF and it works well as given above. so you can consider to try it.

Are you using iText 7 library?

Yes, I use iText7

How I use custom for for my PDF generation is as below which you can find useful.
There are two ways

You can put the font in the res/font/.. folder and use it.
You can put the font in assets/.. and use it.


The problem with the first approach is that when you apply Proguard it will not work as expected.

Working Approach

Don't forget to add a font in asset folder

private fun GeneratePDF() {
        try {
            val path =
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                    .toString() + "/MyPDF"

            val file = File(path, "my_file.pdf")

            val pdfWriter = PdfWriter(file)
            val pdfDocument = PdfDocument(pdfWriter)
            val document = Document(pdfDocument)

            val font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(
                "assets/regular.ttf",
                PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H
            )
            document.setFont(font)
            pdfDocument.defaultPageSize = PageSize.A4
            pdfDocument.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, TextFooterEventHandler(document))
            
            val secondLine = Paragraph(
                "${
                    SimpleDateFormat(
                        "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a",
                        Locale.getDefault()
                    ).format(Date())
                } \n Created By : My"
            ).setBold().setFontSize(12f).setItalic()
            document.add(secondLine)

            val line = SolidLine(1f)
            val linebreak = LineSeparator(line)
            document.add(linebreak)
            
            document.close()
           
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

Hope it works for you. Happy Compose :)

Can you share the logic of TextFooterEventHandler class with me?

Just Remove that line because it is not related to this function. It just add the footer in the page. first run and tell me the result. then if needed I'll provide you that logic
